# How to check if a list is empty in Python?

Tags: python, list

The API I'm working with can return empty `[]` lists.

The following conditional statements aren't working as expected:

```
if myList is not None: #not working
    pass

if myList is not []: #not working
    pass
```

What will work?

Comment: Using `!=` instead of `is not` would have made this work, though the `if myList` form is preferred.

Comment: If anyone finds it useful, I created a youtube tutorial comparing the different ways to check if list is empty. API responses are a perfect use case https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8V88bl3tuBQ

Comment: Why not just process the list?  Something like:  for item in myList: <do stuff to item>  That falls through if the list is empty and if it isn't, you just do whatever you were going to do in the first place.

Comment: `if myList == []: print("The list is empty!")`

Comment: try to use `!=` instead of `is not` so it'd work

Comment: Note that `!=` results these days in a `DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.`

Answer (score 209, accepted):

```
if not myList:
  print "Nothing here"
```

Comment: This is the way recommended by PEP8 as Chris Lacasse said in another comment.

Answer (score 23):

I like Zarembisty's answer. Although, if you want to be more explicit,  you can always do:

```
if len(my_list) == 0:
    print "my_list is empty"
```

Comment: You can do that, but it would violate pep 8, which says:
- For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
      sequences are false.

      Yes: if not seq:
           if seq:

      No: if len(seq)
          if not len(seq)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me, Chris Lacasse. I had no known about pep8, earlier

Comment: It would also be a general performance pessimisation: do not spend time counting elements of potentially long collections, if all you need to know is if they are empty.

Comment: @AdN: `len` is an `O(1)` operation, so that's not really an issue. However, it may be faster (I'm not sure) to simply check `if len(myList)`. Of course, if we head down that way, we may as well do `if myList`.

Comment: And the above will crash if my_list is None

Comment: When it comes to Django Rest Framework I had to use this approach to check if a list was empty BUT Defined on the request body, if it was not I needed other error, using the boolean approach overrode the "Field Not Defined error"

Answer (score 20):

Empty lists evaluate to False in boolean contexts (such as `if some_list:`).