# How to check if a variable is empty in python?

Tags: python

I am wondering if python has any function such as php empty function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) which check if the variable is empty with following criteria

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, [`bool`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool). It's not exactly the same -- `'0'` is `True`, but `None`, `False`, `[]`, `0`, `0.0`, and `""` are all `False`.

`bool` is used implicitly when you evaluate an object in a condition like an `if` or `while` statement, conditional expression, or with a boolean operator.

If you wanted to handle strings containing numbers as PHP does, you could do something like:

```
def empty(value):
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return bool(value)
```

Answer (score 26):

See also this previous answer which recommends the `not` keyword

[How to check if a list is empty in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725517/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty-in-python)

It generalizes to more than just lists:

```
>>> a = ""
>>> not a
True

>>> a = []
>>> not a
True

>>> a = 0
>>> not a
True

>>> a = 0.0
>>> not a
True

>>> a = numpy.array([])
>>> not a
True
```

Notably, it will not work for "0" as a string because the string does in fact contain something - a character containing "0". For that you have to convert it to an int:

```
>>> a = "0"
>>> not a
False

>>> a = '0'
>>> not int(a)
True
```

Comment: `not` is not a command, but a keyword. It's also not a function so you don't need (and shouldn't use) the parenthesis. `not` is also implicitly converting to a bool then inverting; you don't always want to invert just to get a boolean.

Comment: Thanks @agf. Corrected it in the post.

Answer (score 8):

Just use `not`:

```
if not your_variable:
    print("your_variable is empty")
```

and for your `0 as string` use:

```
if your_variable == "0":
    print("your_variable is 0 (string)")
```

combine them:

```
if not your_variable or your_variable == "0":
    print("your_variable is empty")
```

Python is about simplicity, so is this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

See section 5.1:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:

`None`

`False`

zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.

any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.

any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.

instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`. [1]

All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return `0` or `False` for false and `1` or `True` for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations `or` and `and` always return one of their operands.)

Comment: This doesn't quite answer his question, "I am wondering if python has any function such as php empty function". This tells him _what is "empty"_ but not how to find out if an arbitrary object is empty or not.

Comment: I suppose my answer is implying that there is a whole section of the documentation that explains *what is "empty"*.  I'd say between the 3 answers to this question we've exhausted the majority of the use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **not** keyword.

```
if not a
    print("a is empty")
```