# WxTimer doesn't let the wxFrame close

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to debug this code, the Frame doesn't close on pressing the 'x' button, however when I comment out the wxTimer I am able to close it. Upon googling I found this - http://wiki.wxpython.org/Timer and I tried to bind an event to the top level window however the onClose function is never called on pressing the 'x' button.

Any suggestions?

```
class matplotsink(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, title, queue):
        # wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        #self.datagen = DataGen()
        #self.data = self.datagen.next()

        self.data = []

        self.parent = parent
        self.title = title
        self.queue = queue

        self.paused = False

        #self.create_menu()
        #self.create_status_bar()

        self.toplevelcontainer = wx.GetApp().GetTopWindow()
        self.toplevelcontainer.CreateStatusBar()


        print 'Hey'
        # menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        # fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        # fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW, '&New')
        # fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, '&Open')
        # fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, '&Save')
        # menuBar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        # self.toplevelcontainer.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  


        self.toplevelcontainer.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onCloseFrame)
        self.create_main_panel()

        self.redraw_timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.draw_callback, self.redraw_timer)

        self.redraw_timer.Start(100)

    def onCloseFrame(self,event):
        print 'Hey1'
        self.redraw_timer.Stop()
        self.toplevelcontainer.Destroy()
        self.toplevelcontainer.Close()
```

Comment: Word of advice: If you are trying to update matplotlib every 100 ms, this is probably a bad idea. Better use an event-driven update, not a polling one with the Timer. matplotlib is fast, but not super-fast.

Comment: I tried using the funcAnimation method of matplotlib but apparently for some reason my entire Frame doesn't show when I call funcAnimation, also the update function (a parameter to funcAnimation) does not get called (I tried with a 'print' statement)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see that `onCLoseFrame()` does not get called. Quite to the contrary, `self.toplevelcontainer.Destroy()` retriggers `EVT_CLOSE` ad infinitum until the maximum recursion depth is reached. This is the reason `self.toplevelcontainer` never gets closed.

Instead of trying to destroy the top level window yourself, let the event handler do its job by skipping after you are done with the cleanup:

```
    def onCloseFrame(self, event):
        # ...
        self.redraw_timer.Stop() #cleanup, important!
        event.Skip()
```

You can check [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117264/2683116) (the link in the answer) for an explanation. As I have seen, the particular wxPython-wiki entry for wx.Timer is not very useful.

Comment: I tried this and no change. I am still not able to close the window. I am trying to update matplotlib using redraw_timer and I did read about certain issues when the window freezes while updating the data set for matplotlib. Is that the issue?

Comment: UPDATE: It works but it takes into effect after a certain period of time and the rest of the widgets on the frame don't seem to work smoothly, however upon changing the update limit of timer to 500 everything seems to work fine.
Is there any way that I can achieve both? Update the graph at a fast interval and not let my window freeze?